# How to retrieve the index values of first 5 in r?

Tags: r

I sorted a data set which is a vector and i want to retrieve the indices of the first five values in the vector.

I used the following code to sort data set and retrieve the first five values. But i am not sure how to retrieve its indices.

```
head(sort(dsq), 5)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "retrieve its indices"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want `order` which will return the indice of element that can be used to permute the sequence into ascending or descending order.

```
order(dsq)
```

Comment: How do i retrieve the top 5 using the order function?

Comment: Try: `dsq[order(dsq,decreasing=T)[1:5]]`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `index.return=TRUE` argument in the `sort`.  It will return a `list` of length 2.  From this, extract the index (`$ix`) and get the first 5 values with `head`.

```
head(sort(dsq, index.return=TRUE)$ix, 5)
```